# Count how many maps $f$ on $A$ where $f\circ f=1_A$?

Tags: combinatorics, category-theory, solution-verification

Given that $|A|=n$, count how many maps $f$ on $A$ such that $f\circ f=1_A$?

My thought: There will be at most $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ pairs $(a,b)$ s.t. $fa=b, fb=a$. Then I choose each possible pairs, but since the order of choosing them out doesn't matter, divide it by $k!$. So I got:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-2j}{2},$$

Is it correct? Why it looks so complicated?

Since the problem is come from a book about category theory intro. I tagged it category theory.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** If $I_n$ is the number of involutions of a set with $n$ elements, one has
$$I_{n+1} = I_n + n I_{n-1}$$

Comment: They even have their Wikipedia page [Telephone Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics))

Comment: @Gribouillis: Thanks for the link.